# Merge Arrays to form Dictionaries - iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two 2D arrays like

```
Array1 = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]

Array2 = [(x, y), (x, y), (x, y)]
```

I want to form a dictionary like `"coordinates" = [{"x":"1", "y":"2"}, {"x":"3", "y":"4"},{"x":"5", "y":"6"}]`

How do i do it?

Comment: Second array always have just x and y?

Comment: Yes! Only x and y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention in comment second array always have x and y then there is no need to loop through that array, You need just iterate first array like this.

```
NSMutableArray *dicArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSArray *subArray in array1) {
    NSDictionary *dic = @{ @"x": [subArray firstObject], @"y": [subArray lastObject] };
    [dicArray addObject:dic];
}
NSLog(@"%@",dicArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Alternative:

```
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSArray* arr1 in Array1) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSArray* arr2 in Array2) {
        [dict setValue:arr1.firstObject forKey:arr2.firstObject];
        [dict setValue:arr1.lastObject forKey:arr2.lastObject];
    }
    [finalArray addObject:dict];
}

NSLog(@"%@", finalArray);
```